# Cisco ISE 1.3 and 1.4 - Sponsored guest approval email - single click approval possible?

Tags: cisco, wireless, wlc

When self-registering guests generate a request to their Sponsor, how can one create a REST-based link that can approve new Guests with a single click from the email message?

Has anyone successfully done this?

Default options require a login to the Sponsor portal and navigating to the pending users to approve.

Comment: I would be very happy if someone came up with an answer for you, but I suspect this is not easy to do just yet, as I am facing similar challenges with my own ISE platform. I see a combination of two issues here : - ISE needs to determine whether the user who receives the email and clicks on the link belongs to a sponsor group with appropriate permissions for this type of guest. For this it needs to be able to link the email to a sponsor account, and I have not found any way to do this so far.
- ISE needs to authenticate that sponsor somehow (unless the emailed link is considered sufficient pro

Comment: Cisco TAC confirmed this feature does not exist and is not planned.  Write in to your local Cisco Account Rep to request(demand) it be put on the roadmap!

Comment: There may be some progress though. ISE 2.1 finally supports SAMLv2 and has gained the ability through that to link a sponsor account with the email address provided in the guest request. So some of the pieces are ready.